# Bottom-border isn't a crisp 1px line when you hover

Tags: css

When you hover the sentence, the `bottom-border` isn't a crisp 1px line, like when you hover over `photography`. I've set `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` also. http://imdarrien.com/#

```
.project-link-1 {
display: inline;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.project-link-1 a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.project-link-1 > a {
font-family: 'NimbusSansNo5TOT-Regular';
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 16px;
word-spacing: 2px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use transform with percentages. Your content gets antialiased. You could try to remove the transform from `.project_miniwrap` or position it pixel perfect.